# Getting a type's member description

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, system.reflection

I am writing a program which utilises the System.Reflection namespace of the Microsoft .NET 4.0 Framework, however there is a piece of information that I require which I cannot find or does not exist in the namespace.

In Visual Studio when you access a type's members the IntelliSense provides a brief description of the member at hand. For example, the System.Object.Equals method has the description: "Determines whether the specified System.Object is equal to the current System.Object."

Does there exist any methods/properties in the framework which allow me to get the description of a type in an assembly?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That information is not inside the assembly, but is obtained from the matching .xml file - i.e. `foo.dll` can optionally have `foo.dll.xml`. You would need to query the data from there, but note that in many cases this data is not deployed with 3rd-party dlls.

Comment: Does this exist for mscorlib.dll? I can't seem to find mscorlib.dll.xml

Comment: @TheBoss - try mscorlib.xml instead; I don't know why it is different in this case

Comment: I found the files in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\en\, however it is slightly concerning that the files are non-existant in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319. It is very confusing since it does contain, for example, System.Collections.Generic which was not introduced until .NET 3.5.

Comment: @TheBoss -  System.Collections.Generic is 2.0